# Hello, I'm trying to figure out how factory constructor working in dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, factory

I've took the code from flutter.dev which use factory for fetching data from the internet.

```
import 'dart:convert';

Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Album.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Album {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Album({this.userId, this.id, this.title});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

I had tried to repeat it in my code but it didn't work. And I'm confused why it doesn't work because I do the same as in the example.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() {

  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    "photo": "another data",
    "id": "dsiid1dsaq",
  };

  return Album.fromJson(map);
}

class Album {

  String photo;
  String id;

  Album({this.photo, this.id});

  factory Album.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Album(
      photo: json['photo'],
      id: json['id'],
    )`
  }
}
```

It tells me that: "A value of type 'Album' can't be returned from function 'fetchAlbum' because it has a return type of 'Future'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this may help you.

```
Future<Album> fetchAlbum() async {

  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    "photo": "another data",
    "id": "dsiid1dsaq",
  };

  return Album.fromJson(map);
}
```

or like this

```
Album fetchAlbum() {

  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    "photo": "another data",
    "id": "dsiid1dsaq",
  };

  return Album.fromJson(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the `factory` constructor itself. The problem is you're declaring your function `fetchAlbum` to be of type `Future<Album>` when in reality it returns just a Syncronous `Album`...

The example from the Flutter Documentation has a return type of `Future<T>` because it uses the `async` and `await` keyword when dealing with network requests so it returns a `Future`.

Change:

```
Album fetchAlbum() {

  Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    "photo": "another data",
    "id": "dsiid1dsaq",
  };

  return Album.fromJson(map);
}
```